# Display table values for select in anonymous code block in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm looking for a working example for my problem and can't find the right one... I want to display my `SELECT's` output in `PL/SQL Developer`. How to do this in this piece of code:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM MyTable;
END;
```

How to diplay a grid with values?

Comment: Are you using SQLdeveloper, SQLplus or something ? Try selecting the sentence "select * from Mytable" and press ctrl+entry or click the button up to execute it.

Comment: Why have you wrapped your `select` in a PL/SQL block? Which window are you running this in, within PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: I just simplified my code. Normally it's more complicated and has to be done in a block. I want to display results in the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from a Test window (but not, as far as I'm aware, from an SQL windows or a Command window.

In your anonymous block, open your query as a cursor using a bind variable:

```
BEGIN
   OPEN :rc FOR
      SELECT * FROM MyTable;
END;
```

Then add a variable with the same name as the bind variable, without the leading colon, of type Cursor:

[image]

Then execute your block. When it has completed click the tiny ellipsis next to the variable (circled in red in the picture above). The cursor contents will be shown in an SQL window as a result set:

[image]